# Fibonacci and Limit Question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How large must n be to ensure that limit as x goes to infinity of $F_{n+1}/F_{n}$ is within $10^{-1}$ of the limit?

What about $10^{-k}$ of the limit?

Can someone provide me with the method for doing this? I am going to assume that I need to use the definition of a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  You can use [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Philippe_Marie_Binet) $F_n=\frac {\phi^n-\psi^n}{\sqrt 5}$  Form the fraction $\frac {F_{n+1}}{F_n}$ and you need the effect of the $\psi^n$ term to be small enough.

Comment: Yeah binders formula looks good but how do I go from that to showing the limit?

Comment: $\phi^n$ is larger than $\psi^n$, so divide the fraction by $\phi^{n+1}$ and you get a couple of small terms.

Comment: I am still very confused could you possibly write it out? I have attempted this probably for fun for several days and and this point I'm just frustrated ://

Comment: I would really appreciate it. It seems like you really know what you're saying

Comment: Better to divide by $\phi^n$.  You get $\frac {F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\phi\frac {1+x}{1+y}\approx \phi(1+x-y)$ so you need $x-y$ small enough. As they are $n$th powers of a number less than $1$, they will become small.  You just need to find the power that makes them small enough.  Can you find $x,y$?